# HTML background-image not showing on screen

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an full width image above my nav bar, but I cant even get the image to show on screen.  Here is my simple HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper" />
  </body>
</html>
```

And the css:

```
.wrapper {
  background-image: url(../assets/bridge.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I see the jpg made it to my browser and can click on it in my resources, so there is no problem with the path.  The screen is still blank and showing nothing.  Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Just curious, why not setting the background on the `body`?

Comment: YOU should use this `image` in `body` `background`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `height:100%` is functionally useless, and your div resultingly has no height.

If you give the div a fixed height, the image should [appear as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/VspYx/).

Alternatively if you want the background image to apply to the background of the page, you can apply it to the `<html>` element and avoid the whole wrapper, 100% debacle.

```
html {
     background-image: url(../assets/bridge.jpg);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: +1 for This is because height:100% is functionally useless, am also agree with you `height:100% ` `div` resultingly has no `height`.

Comment: FYI: `height:100%` is not _in general_ “functionally useless” – but it depends on the parent element having an explicit `height` of its own, not just `auto`.

Comment: @CBroe - correct! It's also probably worth mentioning that `height:100%` will (as most people expect in the general case) give the element viewport-height if it is removed from normal page flow with `position:absolute` or `position:fixed`

Comment: I would, however, argue that `height:100%` is functionally useless in precisely the general case... It's incredibly useful to solve a number of specific problems that are mostly not what people are trying to use it for. There's a gap in CSS where users would like to tell an element to stretch itself between its parent's top and bottom edges, and the style they expect to do that has been very deliberately and reasonably defined to do something quite different.... `</rant>`

Comment: _“to stretch itself between its parent's top and bottom edges”_ – yes, but that’s what can lead to unsolvable problems, if the height of the parent depends on its children in return. If #parent is supposed to be stretched by #child, and I give #child, say, `height:110%` – then we are in quite a bit of a pickle … and I think that’s why they put it into the spec that percentage heights only work for parents with an explicit height set.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/dolours/JcxLm/2/ Give a specific height, Height 100% is meaningless

```
.wrapper {
  background-image: url(../assets/bridge.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `<div class="wrapper"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the image isn't showing because there is no content within the div and therefore it's size is 0. Try setting the width and height to a set size, something like 200px to test out this theory. Also I would change your code to:

```
<div class="wrapper"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use css for body tag, the css of body will be like this:

```
body{
   background: url(../assets/bridge.jpg) center top no-repeat;
}
```

i think it will work for you, if you want just background image.